# Replacing netcat using kali linux

Tags: python-2.7

This is the error I am receiving:

```
  [*] Exception! Exiting.
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "bhnet.py", line 59, in <module>
      client.close()
       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Below is the code straight from the book I am following. Is there anyone that can tell me what is going on?

```
import sys, socket, getopt, threading, subprocess

       #def some global variables
       listen = False
       command = False
       upload = False
        execute = ""
       target = ""
        upload_destination = ""
       port = 0
       client = socket

def usage():
    print "bhp net tool"
    print
    print "usage:bhpnet.py -t target_host -p port"
    print "-l --listen -listen on [host]:[port] for incoming connections"
    print "-e --execute=file_to_run -execute the given file upon - receiving   a connection"
    print "-c --command -initialize a command shell"
    print "-u --upload=destination -upon receiving connection upload a -file    and write to [destination]"
    print 
    print
    print "examples:"
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c"
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -u =c:\\target.exe"
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc.passwd\""
    print "echo 'python' | ./bhpnet.py -t 192.168.8.135 -p 135"
    sys.exit(0)

     def client_sender(buffer):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   try:
    #connect to our target host
    client.connect((target,port))
    if len(buffer):
        client.send(buffer)

        while True:
        #now wait for data back
        recv_len = 1
        response = ""
        while recv_len:
            data = client.recv(4096)
            recv_len = len(data)
            response+= data
            if recv_len < 4096:
                break
    print response,

    #wait for more input
    buffer = raw_input("")
    buffer += "\n"
    #send it off
    client.send(buffer)

    except:
    print "[*] Exception! Exiting."
    # tear down the connection
    client.close()
    enterkey()
   def server_loop():
    global target
    # if no target is defined, we listen on all interfaces
    if not len(target):
        target = "0.0.0.0"
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((target,port))
    server.listen(5)
   while True:
    client.socket, addr = server.accept()
    #spin off a thread to handle our new client
    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler,    args=(client_socket,))
    client_thread.start()

   def run_command(command):
    #trim the newline
    command = command.rstrip()
    #run the command and get the output back
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,   shell=True)
        except:
        output = "Failed to execute command.\r\n"
        #send the output back to the client
        return output

   def client_handler(client_socket):
    global upload
    global command
    global execute
    #check for upload
    if len(upload_destination):
        #read in all of our bytes and write to our destination
        file_buffer = ""
        # keep reading data until none is available
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        else:
            file_buffer += data
        # now we take these bytes and try to write them out
    try:
        file_descriptor = open(upload_destination, "wb")
        file_descriptor.write(file_buffer)
        file_descriptor.close()
        # acknowledge that we wrote the file out
    except:
        client_socket.send("Failed to save file to %s\r\n"          %                   upload_destination)
   #check for command execution
   if len(execute):
    # run the command
    output = run_command(execute)
    client_socket.send(output)

    # now we go into another loop if a command shell was requested
    if command:
    while True:
        #show a simple prompt
        client_socket.send("<BHP:#> ")
        # now we recive until we see a linefeed
        cmd_buffer = ""
        while "\n" not in cmd_buffer:
            cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)
        # send back the command output
        response = run_command(cmd_buffer)
        #send back the response
        client_socket.send(response)

    def main():
     global listen
     global port
     global execute
     global command
     global upload_destination
     global target

      if not len(sys.argv[1]):
        usage()

      #read the commandline options
      try:
         opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hle:t:p:cu:",         ["help",      "listen", "execute", "target", "port", "command", "upload"])
       except getopt.GetoptError as err:
          print str(err)
            usage()
        for o,a in opts:
            if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
          elif o in ("-l", "--listen"):
            listen = True
          elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
            execute = a
          elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
            command = True
          elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
            upload_destination = a
          elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
            target = a
          elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
            port = int(a)
          else:
            assert False, "unhandled option"

       #are we going to listen or just send data from stdin?
     if not listen and len(target) and port >0:
       #read in the buffer from the commandline
       #this is will block, so send ctrl-D if not sending input
       #to stdin
       buffer = sys.stdin.read()
       #send data off
       client_sender(buffer)
     #are we going to listen and potentially
     #upload things, execute commands, and drop a shell back
     #depending on our command line options above

   if listen:
     server_loop()
     main()
```

Comment: i know this code got messed up posting it here

Comment: If you knows it why you didn't format it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#This code is tested and will work for you
import sys
import socket
import getopt
import threading`enter code here`
import subprocess
import pdb

# globals
listen        = False
command        = False
upload        = False
execute        = ""
target        = ""
upload_destination = ""
port         = 0

def usage():
    print "BHP Net Tool"
    print
    print "Usage: bhpnet.py -t target_host -p port"
    print "-l --listen                listen on [host]:[port] for incoming connections"
    print "-e --execute=file_to_run   execute the given file upon receiving a connection"
    print "-c --command               initialize a command shell"
    print "-u --upload                upon receiving connection upload a file and write to [destination]"
    print
    print
    print "Examples: "
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c"
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -u=c:\\target.exe"
    print "bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e='cat /etc/passwd'"
    print "echo 'ABCDEFGHI' | ./bhpnet.py -t 192.168.11.12 -p 135"
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    global listen
    global port
    global execute
    global command
    global upload_destination
    global target

    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hle:t:p:cu:",["help", "listen", "execute", "target", "port", "command", "upload"])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print str(err)
        usage()

    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
        elif o in ("-l", "--listen"):
            listen = True
        elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
            execute = a
        elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
            command = True
        elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
            upload_destination = a
        elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
            target = a
        elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
            port = int(a)

#        else:
#            assert False, "Unhandled Option"

    if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:

        buffer = sys.stdin.read()

        client_sender(buffer)

    if listen:
        server_loop()



def client_sender(buffer):

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        client.connect((target, port))

        if len(buffer):
            client.send(buffer)

        # wait for data back
        while True:

            recv_len = 1
            response = ""

            while recv_len:
                data     = client.recv(4096)
                recv_len = len(data)
                response += data

                if recv_len < 4096:
                    break

            print response,

            # wait for more input
            buffer = raw_input("")
            buffer += "\r\n"

            print "[*] Sending: '%s'" % buffer
            client.send(buffer)
    except Exception as err:
        print "[*] Exception! Exiting. %s" % err

        client.close()

def server_loop():
    global target

    if not len(target):
        target = "0.0.0.0"

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((target,port))

    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        client_socket,addr = server.accept()

        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, 
                                           args=(client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()

def run_command(command):

    command = command.rstrip()
    print "[*] Processing command: %s" % command
    try:

        output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

    except Exception as err:
        output = "Failed to execute command.\r\n"

    return output

def client_handler(client_socket):
    global upload
    global execute
    global command

    if len(upload_destination):

        file_buffer = ""

        while True: 

            data = client_socket.recv(1024)

            if not data:
                break
            else:
                file_buffer += data

        try:
            file_descriptor = open(upload_destination, "wb")
            file_descriptor.write(file_buffer)
            file_descriptor.close()

            client_socket.send("Successfully saved file to %s\r\n" % upload_destination)

        except:
            client_socket.send("Successfully saved file to %s\r\n" % upload_destination)


    # check for command execution
    if len(execute):
        output = run_command(execute)
        client_socket.send(output)

    # another loop if command shell requested
    if command:
        while True:
            client_socket.send("<BHP:#> ")

            cmd_buffer = ""
            while "\n" not in cmd_buffer:
                cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)

            print "[*] Recv'd command: %s" % cmd_buffer
            response = run_command(cmd_buffer)

            client_socket.send(response)


main()
```

Comment: The above will work.  In the book, change './bhnet.py' wiith 'python bhpnet.py'

Comment: Can you add some line explaining what you change / why ?